# Built a JSON from string pieces

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I work with a line chart in ExtJS4 now. The chart is based on the data of the store. The store change its data with help 'loadRawData()' function. 
Familiar situation, isn't it?

AJAX sends strings every 10 seconds and I need to built JSON from this pieces of strings. I'm trying:

```
success: function(response) {
    var requestMassive = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
    var jArray = [];
                for(var i=0;i<requestMassive.length;i++){
                    var firstPiece = JSON.parse(response.responseText)[i].date; 
                    var secondPiece = JSON.parse(response.responseText)[i].connectCount;
                    var recording = "{'machinesPlayed':"+firstPiece+", 'machinesOnline':"+secondPiece+"}";
                    jArray.push(recording);
                }

                jArray = '['+jArray+']';
                store.loadRawData(jArray);
}
```

But it is wrong way. How to do it properly?

Comment: how did you define your store and model?

Comment: Ext.define('Connections', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['date', 'connect']
});

Comment: var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Connections',
    data: [
        { date: 586787897, connect: 43 },
        { date: 45345435, connect: 56 },
        ...
    ]
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `loadData()` function instead of `loadRawData()`. `loadData()` only needs an array of objects.

```
success: function(response) {
   var requestMassive = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
   var jArray = [];
      for(var i=0;i<requestMassive.length;i++){
         jArray.push({ machinesPlayed: requestMassive[i].date, machinesOnline: requestMassive[i].connectCount});
      }

      store.loadData(jArray);
}
```

Comment: please check the checkmark next to this answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

I didnt get what you are trying to achieve.But it can be formed this way.Try this out.

```
var recording = {
  "machinesPlayed" : firstPiece,
  "machinesOnline" : secondPiece
 }
jArray.push(recording);

OR
jArray.push({
    "machinesPlayed" : firstPiece,
    "machinesOnline" : secondPiece
});
```